# ErrorException in AuthServiceProvider.php Undefined variable in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to make a acl in Laravel 5.4. On 5.2 it used to work like this, but 5.4 is not like this anymore and it gives this error message:

ErrorException in AuthServiceProvider.php Undefined variable:gate

Could anyone explain why it is not working and how to fix it?
Here is my code:

```
 public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    $gate->define('auth', function($user, $role=NULL){
        if($role === NULL){
            $actions = Route::current()->getAction();

            if(! isset($actions['role']))
                return false;
            $role = $actions['role'];
        }
        $objRole = new Role();
        $roles = $objRole->roles($user->id);
        if(in_array($role, $roles))
            return true;
        return false;

    });

}
```

Comment: `$gate` isn't defined anywhere? Would be great to see where it's being defined.

Comment: It is being defined here, or am i doing it wrong?
$gate->define('auth', function($user, $role=NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Gate as a facade, add `use Gate;` and change

```
$gate->define('auth', function($user, $role=NULL)
```

to

```
Gate->define('auth', function($user, $role=NULL)
```